# Return multiple values from a function in Angular and use those values inside HTML div tag. The return values can't be assigned to variable in TS file

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a function which returns a string, a css class and a boolean like this [false, green_box]. I want to utilise this values in below HTML but unfortunately I am unable to do so. How can I access the values? Since the function is called multiple times inside the HTML file I cannot assign the return values in a variable in typescript file.

Please note that I can use different function to return boolean value but the goal is to find a way to utilize multiple values returned from a function in HTML.

Below is my HTML

```
<div *ngIf="getClass('investing', 'plan')[0]"
     class="prio_box dnd_move"
     data-drag="list-1"
     data-drag-index="0">

  <span [ngClass]="getClass('investing', 'plan')[1]" 
      class="dnd_move clr-box">
  </span>

  <span class="drag_content dnd_move">Plan</span>

</div>
```

Here is my function,

```
getClass(component: string, value: any) {
    component = component.toLowerCase();
    value = value.replace(/\s/g, "");
    let pathValue = this.control[component]
      ? this.control[component.toLowerCase()][value]
      : null;
    this.allGreen.add(pathValue);
    return [pathValue == Status.Yes
      ? "green_box"
      : pathValue == Status.DontKnow
      ? "yellow_box"
      : "red_box",
      pathValue == Status.Yes
      ? false
      : pathValue == Status.DontKnow
      ? true
      : true];

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="getClass('investing', 'plan') as class">
<div *ngIf="class[0]"
     class="prio_box dnd_move"
     data-drag="list-1"
     data-drag-index="0">

  <span class="dnd_move clr-box {{class[1] || ''}}">
  </span>

  <span class="drag_content dnd_move">Plan</span>

</div>
</ng-container>
```

Using this way, you can prevent function from being called multiple times.

Comment: I tried your approach but got this error,
ERROR Error: NgClass can only toggle CSS classes expressed as strings, got true

Comment: Can you please let me know, what does class[1] will hold  ( example value )?

Comment: class[1] will hold a string value and class[0] will hold a boolean. The getClass() will return an array.
Example - ["green_box", true]

Comment: Okay, so in that case, you can not pass string to ngClass. 
I have updated the answer for your use case.